# Merging two columns for excel pivot report

Tags: excel, pivot, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have data in my excel sheet that looks like the follows:

[image]

For the sake of explanation I have hidden some columns (Please ignore them). I have taken pivot of the view you see above and the output of that is as follows:

[image]

However, I am expecting an output similar to the following, where the L1 and L1C (which denote the same thing) are displayed as one entity (as if it came from one column itself)

[image]

Does excel's pivot feature provide something to this effect?

ps: if you want access to data I've used visit my google doc file: click [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArJoUDcjmKXbdGtCNE9kcFhaUU5saHlVci1ZQW9tVlE)

Update:

What I had done to achieve the desired result was generate the desired columns via excel formulas. (Hence you would notice columns after the Name field in the spreadsheet I shared above). Is this the only way you can approach this problem in excel during pivoting?

Comment: Why is it a problem to just add columns with the concatenations? If those concatenations are important to you you might as well just have them in seperate columns. Are you running low on the 16,384 columns that you can have per sheet in excel 2007/2010?

Answer (score 1):

Having set up the data and pivot as in the first two screenshots, you could select a cell in the pivot table and try running this code to get the last screenshot:

```
Sub UpdatePivot()
With ActiveCell.PivotTable
    AddPivotLabels .PivotFields("l1"), .PivotFields("l1c")
    AddPivotLabels .PivotFields("l2"), .PivotFields("l2c")
    AddPivotLabels .PivotFields("l3"), .PivotFields("l3c")
End With
End Sub

Sub AddPivotLabels(pName1 As PivotField, pName2 As PivotField)
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To pName1.PivotItems.Count
    pName1.PivotItems(i).Value = pName1.PivotItems(i).SourceName & _
                            " (" & pName2.PivotItems(i).SourceName & ")"
Next i
End Sub
```

*Note*: This assumes that the relationships are 1-1 you probably want to check this before running on larger datasets.